# Descriptions of an elite mind

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

> My starting part discerns the green from white and blue and red;
>   I use it to describe myself, agree with what's been said.
>
> My second part's an aurous lass, a symbol of a state,
>   dilemma of a Nordic prince, result that's almost great.
>
> My third part is an old film of a manhunt really tense,
>   and it describes one kilo or a shirt that's not immense.
>
> My fourth describes an ocean, or a colour, thoughts profound;
>   a voice that sounds impressive, something buried underground.
>
> My fifth describes an ocean, or some music, thoughts of woe;
>   you look up on a cloudless day, and off to jail you go.
>
> My whole describes a mind that really turned out quite elite;
>   to beat us at our own game was a truly monstrous feat.

Who am I?

Comment: Beautiful rhyme! Reminds me of a @HughMeyers riddle! DVL17 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D **Edit:** Could you be Rot13(Nyoreg Rvafgrva? Na nantenz bs uvf anzr vf "ryvgr oenva arfg").

Comment: Thanks @user477343! That guy does have some great rhymes. Won't spoil in comments, but the anagram is certainly apt :P

Comment: @user477343 Wow. Now I'm even famous for riddles I *didn't* write.  :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> **IBM Deep Blue**

My starting part discerns the green from white and blue and red;
I use it to describe myself, agree with what's been said.

> **I**: The “eye” discerns colors. “I” = myself. “Aye” = agree

My second part's an aurous lass, a symbol of a state,
dilemma of a Nordic prince, result that's almost great.

> **B**: Bea Arthur was a Golden Girl. The beehive is the state symbol of Utah. Hamlet pondered, “To be or not to be”. “B”, as in a grade, is good not great.

My third part is an old film of a manhunt really tense,
and it describes one kilo or a shirt that's not immense.

> **M**: *M* is a movie involving a manhunt, the Roman numeral for one thousand, and abbreviation for medium.

My fourth describes an ocean, or a colour, thoughts profound;
a voice that sounds impressive, something buried underground.

> **DEEP**: can describe the ocean, colors, profound thoughts, voices, or underground things.

My fifth describes an ocean, or some music, thoughts of woe;
you look up on a cloudless day, and off to jail you go.

> **BLUE**: describes the ocean, music (“the blues”), sadness, the sky, and the police.

My whole describes a mind that really turned out quite elite;
to beat us at our own game was a truly monstrous feat.

> **IBM DEEP BLUE** was the first computer chess-playing system to win both a chess game and a chess match against a reigning world champion under regular time controls, beating Garry Kasparov and acheiving a milestone for AI.

Comment: pretty great answer, what was your starting point on this one..

Comment: 4th and 5th came to me pretty easily, which led me to the full answer. I had to work a little bit for some of the individual subclues, notably in the 2nd.

Comment: This is correct. Nice work!